# Flutter Sign Up Page Where First and Last Name are Next To Each Other

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I currently am creating a sign up page for an app and want my layout to be different. I currently have fields for First Name, Last Name, Email address, Password, and Confirm Password. I need to add another field below the Name fields so I want to move Last Name up next to First Name.

I want to lay out my app similar to this:
[Desired sign up layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkJyn.png)

But my App is currently looking like this:
[current signup layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVjrC.png)

The code below shows how I sloppily ended up with my current layout.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [Color(0xFF6cc5de), Colors.white]),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 200.0,
              child: Image.asset('assets/carebloomlogo.png'),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Text(
                'C A R E • B L O O M',
                style: GoogleFonts.raleway(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 35,
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF3E8094),
                    )),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 85,
              child: TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                focusNode: FNMFocusNode,
                cursorColor: Color(0xFF3E8094),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "First Name",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: FNMFocusNode.hasFocus
                            ? Colors.black
                            : Color(0xFF3E8094)),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF3E8094)))),
                onChanged: (input) => _firstname = input,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 85,
              child: TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                focusNode: LNMFocusNode,
                cursorColor: Color(0xFF3E8094),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Last Name",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: LNMFocusNode.hasFocus
                            ? Colors.black
                            : Color(0xFF3E8094)),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF3E8094)))),
                onChanged: (input) => _lastname = input,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 85,
              child: TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                focusNode: EmailFocusNode,
                cursorColor: Color(0xFF3E8094),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Email",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: EmailFocusNode.hasFocus
                            ? Colors.black
                            : Color(0xFF3E8094)),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF3E8094)))),
                onChanged: (input) => _email = input,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 85,
              child: TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                focusNode: PassFocusNode,
                cursorColor: Color(0xFF3E8094),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Password",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: PassFocusNode.hasFocus
                            ? Colors.black
                            : Color(0xFF3E8094)),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF3E8094)))),
                onChanged: (input) => _email = input,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 85,
              child: TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                focusNode: RePassFocusNode,
                cursorColor: Color(0xFF3E8094),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Re-Enter Password",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: RePassFocusNode.hasFocus
                            ? Colors.black
                            : Color(0xFF3E8094)),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF3E8094)))),
                onChanged: (input) => _email = input,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 300,
              height: 60,
              child: new ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('New User? Sign Up!'),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Color(0xFF3E8094),
                  onPrimary: Colors.white,
                  shadowColor: Color(0xFF6cc5de),
                  elevation: 5,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF6CC5DE))),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
            // ElevatedButton(
            //   onPressed: _launchURL,
            //   child: Text('No Account? Sign Up!'),
            //   style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Color(0xFF3E8094)),
            // ),
            //loginMethod: auth.anonLogin)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried switching between, rows and columns, throwing rows in columns, trying a grid (probably incorrectly), but nothing is getting me where I want to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs to be a column with 4 elements: a row that has two fields (first and last), then a field for email, then a field for password, then a field for confirm.  I think the only thing you're missing is starting with Row() as the first of the children: of the outer Column().